# Backtracking, Text Segmentation

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, text-segmentation

I could not figure out this brainstorming algorithm question! Could some one help?

*--------Description--------*

**Suppose you are a scientist who are searching for certain kinds of genes. You know that a gene you are
looking for should be formed of the following blocks**\

`AT
GG
CTAC`

We call these blocks as 'valid'. All other blocks are called 'invalid'. Now given a gene consisting of symbols

'A', 'G', 'C', 'T' you should identify if the given gene could be formed with valid blocks.
Examples of genes which can be formed using valid blocks:

`GGATATCTAC
CTACGGGG`

Examples of genes which can not be formed using valid blocks:

`CCC
GGCAC`

```
Question!
1. How many possible choice you have after each reduction?
2. Try to draw a recursion tree for this algorithm
3. What kind of data do you need to store after each reduction?
4. Try to write a recurrence relation for the running time of this algorithm.
5. Try to estimate the running time from the above recurrence relation. Is running time exponential or
polynomial in terms of n, the length of a gene?
```

Comment: What is a `reduction`? Examples would be nice.

Comment: Construct a DFA

Answer (score 3):

python code to do the backtrack with complexity n*n*l with n is the number of blocks here 3 and L is the gene length. For the tree I print the current text then ? then the element I test to add.

```
def genes(chaine, elements, result):
  print()
  if(chaine == ""):
      return result
  ctn = 1
  for elem in elements:
      print(" ".join([" "]*len(chaine)*ctn), "".join(result) + "? " + elem, end = '')
      if(chaine.startswith(elem)):
          return genes(chaine[len(elem):], elements, result + [elem])
      ctn = ctn + 1

   return 0


result = genes("GGATGGATCTAC", ["GG", "AT", "CTAC"], [])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
                  ? GG
                GG? GG                                        GG? AT
            GGAT? GG
        GGATGG? GG                        GGATGG? AT
    GGATGGAT? GG                GGATGGAT? AT                        GGATGGAT? CTAC
```

['GG', 'AT', 'GG', 'AT', 'CTAC']

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you Draw Recursion Tree for this algorithm,  `Question  2`

Comment: I update to integrate printing. it's a quick and dirty one.